run tileserver-gl on a server without internet access Error
I am encountering an issue while trying to run tileserver-gl on a server without internet access. I have successfully set up tileserver-gl on other servers using a prepared folder with all necessary files, but on this particular server, I receive the following error:
C:\Users\andreas\Desktop\map> npx tileserver-gl --mbtiles africa.mbtiles

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340
return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
Error: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
\?\C:\Users\andreas\Desktop\map\node_modules\@maplibre\maplibre-gl-native\lib\node-v108\mbgl.node
at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:18)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:107:18)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:132:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\andreas\Desktop\map\node_modules\@maplibre\maplibre-gl-native\platform\node\index.js:5:12)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1255:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1309:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12) {
code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
Node.js v18.18.1

Steps Taken:
Prepared a folder with all necessary files and configurations.
Successfully used this folder on multiple other servers without issues.
Transferred the prepared folder to the problematic server.
Verified that both servers are running Node.js v18.18.1 and are 64-bit.
Confirmed that the mbgl.node file exists in the specified directory.
Rechecked file paths and permissions.
Compared environment variables and configurations between the working and non-working servers.
Ensured there are no system policies or antivirus programs blocking the execution of .node files.
